# heading on a page

Tags: header-footer, ieee-style

I am using IEEE template to write a paper for a conference. The conference requires to put a header on every page and footer on the first page.

I have been able to put footer. But I cannot get the header on every page. Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Comment: Are you restricted in terms of using packages to ease the production of headers/footers? Also, what do you want to print in the header/footer?

Answer (score 1):

Type in the following before your `\begin{document}`

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{}{Header}
```

The easiest thing will be to use the template provided by the conference.